# Does the new scoped user id in facebook graph v2.0 persist between app removal and reinstall?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook's graph api now returns user ids that are scoped to the app, but my concern is that they will change if the user unauthorizes the app and then reauthorizes.

Is this the case?  Or does the scoped id persist between authorizations / installs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A user that authorized your app will always have the id that you got when they authorized the first time. Doesn't matter what they do after that.